# What should the MVC ActionResult return type be for an external HTML ajaxForm post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins, ajaxform

The idee is to post form data from a normal external Html page to another MVC site controller. Then the data is processed almost like using a webservice.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var options = {
    target: '#output',
    success: function(data){ alert('test success'); },
    url: http://localhost:57232/Services/SendFormData,
    dataType:  json
  };

  $('form').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

The ActionResult receives the data correctly in the FormCollection object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendFormData(FormCollection collection)
{
  string s = string.Empty;

  return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Message!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

At this point the success result is returned but when it gets to the external form my browser which is in this case IE tries to save or open the bytes returned instead of calling the success callback function.

Because this page is an external page, and not part of the MVC site I cannot use a View or Partial View. What should the return type be?

Comment: Your "target" option is telling the form plugin to replace the data in #output with the returned data. I'd get rid of that for testing and just rely on the callback success function. Also, I think you'll need to put your url in quotes.

Comment: Any chance your form contains file upload fields?

Comment: Hi, there are no upload fields, majority of the fields are input type hidden which will be used on the server side once posted, the idea is to bypass the querystring which could limit the amount of data. I have included quotes around the url and removed the target option. In both cases were left with the same problem. It doesn't even call the success event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return partialview result :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(Comment feedback)
    {
        if (feedback != null)
        {
            feedback.CommentedOn = DateTime.Now;
            feedback.CommentId += 1;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                BlogPost blogpost = db.BlogPosts.Find(feedback.BlogId);
                if (blogpost != null)
                    blogpost.NoofComments += 1;
                db.Entry(blogpost).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(feedback).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Comments.Add(feedback);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView("CommentSuccess", feedback);
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Comment", feedback);
    }
```

Also in the AjaxForm you need to set the UpdateTargetID:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Form", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainerdiv"     , OnSuccess = "$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');", OnComplete = "OnComplete();" }))
```

in the targetId of the Ajax Form you need to mention the div id where you have to display the response data.

```
<div id="FormContainerdiv">.</div>
@Html.Partial("Comment", item);
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this could solve my problem and I will test ASAP. However I am just a little concerned with the Razor syntax in the calling Html page as it is a normal Html page and not a MVC view.